# Corda Unit Test: Passing List<StateAndRef<State>>

Tags: corda

In corda, I am writing unit test where i need to pass List> for testing. I was passing from api through CordaRPCOps, How can I do same in unit testing ....Plz help

Comment: Can you post the unit test you've written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got answer ... From SignedTransaction.tx.outRef gives required StateAndRef.